Discrepancies in GA4 and Power BI Data
I am encountering discrepancies between GA4 data and Power BI data despite selecting the same dimensions, metrics, and date range in power bi and GA4 portal.
I used the Google Analytics 2.0 connector to import data into Power BI and created a table with only the necessary fields for visuals, avoiding extra metrics or dimensions. But still, the total user numbers still don’t match, and I am unable to determine the root cause of the inaccuracies. Same issue is occurring with session, pageview, bunce rate data as well.
PowerBi Screenshot:
GA4 powrtal Screenshot:

Is there a way to retrieve raw data from Google Analytics and perform analytics in Power BI? If so, could you guide me on the best approach to achieve this?

Verify that:

you are taking data 48/72h before today's date, as data processing becomes stable after that period.
GA4 and Power BI are set to the same time zone. This may significantly affect how monthly totals are calculated.
Power BI and GA4 may aggregate data differently, so make sure that the aggregation method used in Power BI is consistent with the aggregation method used in GA4.

